# .NET ASMX AJAX returned object

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, asmx, datacontract

Suppose I have a modal pop open which is populated using ajax calls and javascript.

I have already written classes for my data objects in the backend which I'd like to use, which come from my database but for arguments sake are just dummy classes:

```
public class Foo {
    public string Property1 { get;set; }
    public string Property2 { get;set; }
}

public class Bar { 
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public int Name { get;set; }
}
```

I need data from both of these objects already received from the database.   I would like to know what the best approach is for returning them back to the client side.  I have already come up with a few ideas:

- Two web methods calls (Seems like an extra XHR request)
- One call which returns an object array, with index zero being Foo and index one being bar.
- Create a new structure which encapsulates these two classes

For this particular example, I could work around it but I feel like this is going to come up a lot within what I am coding and I figured I'd ask before coming up with a solution.  Anyone have any experience/feedback?  If WCF helps me for this particular problem in any way, I'd definitely be willing to make the switch.

I am using jQuery if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, create a wrapper class that includes the two class instances:

```
public class FooBar {
    public Foo foo { get; set; }
    public Bar bar { get; set; }
}
```

This makes sure that, at the client side:

- You do not have to make assumptions on the location of the object based on its index.
- The client code is better readable and maintainable. There is little room for misinterpretation.
- You can have a single return argument for your service operation.

At least, that is my opinion :-)

Comment: Do you still recommend this approach if you only end up using FooBar once, just for the web service call?  I guess you could put the class within the same web service file

Comment: I would still recommend to put up that FooBar class and even create a seperate file for that. You need to know, I'm an architect in daily practice, so focussing on (future) re-usability and maintainability is my daily work. What you personally do not use directly today, could prove of great value to you in the future or to somebody else needing to maintain your code.

Comment: This answer and comment is great.  I was leaning towards this way but I was trying to make sure there wasn't another acceptable way.